# Laravel Model - $connection property not working

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Why this ain't working?

```
class Condition extends Eloquent{

    protected $connection = 'another-database-connection';

}
```

But it turns out it connects to the default database.

Any thoughts?

---

Edit:

The problem is in:

```
protected function fetchColumns($is = null)
{
    if(!empty($this->table)){
        $columns = DB::select('DESCRIBE '.$this->getTable());
        foreach($columns as $column){
            if(!in_array($column, array('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'))){
                $this->tableColumns[] = $column->Field;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that Laravel mixes databases when trying to get the table columns, that's why I get `Table doesn't exist` error. The connection is fine.

Comment: Have you defined your connection in database.php?

Comment: Yes I have. If I change the name of $connection to something else (a database name that doesn't exist), it throws an error.

Comment: could you add the configs to the question?

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
$columns = DB::select('DESCRIBE '.$this->getTable());
```

to:

```
$columns = $this->getConnection()->select('DESCRIBE '.$this->getTable());
```